# How to extract the value of objects and calculate them?

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out how can I extract the value of an attribute in my objects and then calculate them.

So I have as follow:

```
const data = [
   {
      topUp: true, value: 200
   },
   {
      topUp: true, value: 18
   },
   {
      topUp: false, value: 20
   },
   {
      topUp: true, value: 100
   },
]

const totalSpending = data.filter(
   transaction => transaction.topUp == true
);
```

Now I should get 3 objects. From here I want to get the value of each one like [200, 18, 100] and add them together so my `const totalSpending` will be 318.

Comment: You just need to continue your pocessing with a map : `const totalSpending = data.filter( transaction => transaction.topUp ).map(transaction => transaction.value);`

Comment: `transaction.topUp == true` is just a verbose way of saying `transaction.topUp`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve this relatively easily using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
const data = [{topUp: true, value: 200}, {topUp: true, value: 18}, {topUp: false, value: 20}, {topUp: true, value: 100}],

res = data.reduce((acc, {topUp, value}) => topUp ? acc + value : acc, 0);
console.log(res);
```

The above will get the properties `topUp` and `value`, and then add `value` to the accumulator (ie the total sum) if `topUp` is true, if it is `false`, it will return `acc` (and thus won't add to the sum).

Alternatively, you can remove the ternary and use math with booleans:

```js
const data = [{topUp: true, value: 200}, {topUp: true, value: 18}, {topUp: false, value: 20}, {topUp: true, value: 100}],

res = data.reduce((acc, {topUp, value}) => acc + value*topUp, 0);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very nice and clean

Comment: This is better answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` also that is a higher order function available on arrays which will filter out the values as well as add them.

```js
const data = [{
    topUp: true,
    value: 200
  },
  {
    topUp: true,
    value: 18
  },
  {
    topUp: false,
    value: 20
  },
  {
    topUp: true,
    value: 100
  },
]

const totalSpending = data.reduce((aggregator, obj) => {
  return obj.topUp ? aggregator + obj.value : aggregator
}, 0)

console.log(totalSpending)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.reduce`

```js
const data = [
   {
      topUp: true, value: 200
   },
   {
      topUp: true, value: 18
   },
   {
      topUp: false, value: 20
   },
   {
      topUp: true, value: 100
   },
]

const totalSpending = data.filter(
   transaction => transaction.topUp == true
).reduce((previousValue, nextValue) => {
return previousValue + nextValue.value;
}, 0);

console.log(totalSpending);
```

It loops through every entry in the list and reduces it to a single value. See also the [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reduce.asp) page.

Comment: The `+=` is superfluous - `previousValue` is thrown away after the return, so assigning to it is useless. The action of assigning returns the new value assigned, which is then passed to `return` which is then handed over to the next invocation of the `reduce` callback.

Comment: @VLAZ thanks, that makes more sense. I updated my code example.